# Unable to log in to the PostCreateView template

Tags: django

I have built a blog project and I can't access the PostCreateView for some unknown reason.

I keep getting Page 404 error although I have in the urls patterns

I am also getting the error raised by

```
score.views.PostDetailView
```

Here is the views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'design']
    template_name = "post_form.html"
    success_url = "/score/"
    success_message = "Your Post has been submitted"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.designer = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

here is the PostDetail Views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        total_likes = post.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked
        return context
```

Here is the Urls.py

```
app_name = 'score'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='score'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
]
```

here is the nav bar html that is taking me to the page

```
  <a class="nav-link waves-effect" href="{% url 'score:post-create' %}" >Upload Post</a>
```

here is the post_form template

```
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4" style="padding-top: 20px;">Upload Your Post</legend>
                        {{ form|crispy }}

                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-info ml-0" type="submit">Upload</button>
                    </div>        
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `<slug:slug>` will capture values like `new` as well. So that path will "fire", and the view will find out that there is no `Post` object with `'new'` as `slug`.

You can swap the `path(…)`s, but then you can never access a `Post` with as slug `new`. As a rule of thumb it is better to make `path(…)`s that are *not* overlapping, for example:

```
app_name = 'score'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='score'),
    path('post/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
]
```